# Getting selected option value from controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

[image]

I'm making a Spring MVC project, and I have this form in my .jsp

**JSP**

```
 <form:form action="/admin/assign/add" modelAttribute="cafeTable">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="tableNumber">
                    <spring:message text="Table's Number"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <form:select path="tableNumber" action = "select">
                <form:options items="${tableNumbers}"></form:options>
            </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="${user.fullName}">
                    <spring:message text="Waiter's name"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <form:select path="${user.fullName}" action = "select">
                <c:forEach items="${listUser}" var="user">
                    <option value="${user.fullName}">${user.fullName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="assign"
           value="<spring:message text="Assign"/>"/>
</form:form>
```

So I have `User` and `CafeTable` models, but my model attribute is `CafeTable`.

With the submit button I need to get both selected values in my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/assign/add", params = "assign", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String assign(@ModelAttribute("cafeTable") CafeTable cafeTable) {

    //set cafeTable's UserID field matching selected fullName value

    tableService.addTable(cafeTable);
    return "admin";
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Currently what are the values you are getting? CafeTable should contain tableNumber property and it should be filled with the value

Comment: Yes, CafeTable does contain tableNumber, but I also need to get User's ID  (by getting User's fullName), so that I can set CafeTable's UserID field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form:form action="/admin/assign/add" modelAttribute="cafeTable">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="tableNumber">
                    <spring:message text="Table's Number"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
 <input type="hidden" value="${user.fullName}" name="fullname">
            <form:select path="tableNumber" action = "select">
                <form:options items="${tableNumbers}"></form:options>
            </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="${user.fullName}">
                    <spring:message text="Waiter's name"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <form:select path="${user.fullName}" action = "select">
                <c:forEach items="${listUser}" var="user">
                    <option value="${user.fullName}">${user.fullName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="assign"
           value="<spring:message text="Assign"/>"/>
</form:form>
```

If you don't have fullname property in CafeTable try to add a hidden field inside form:form  like

```
<input type="hidden" value="${user.fullName}" name="fullname">
```

and add a optional request parameter into your controller like below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/assign/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(@RequestParam("fullname") String fullname,@Valid @ModelAttribute("cafeTable") CafeTable cafeTable) {

//now you can access full name from fullname variable here

            ....
        }
```

I haven't tested this code.

Comment: but fullName is User's property, not CafeTable's, how can I get it from CafeTable?